# Вывод в текстбокс сообщений в реальном времени в wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Что лучше использовать при данной задаче. Мне нужно на форме WPF  в паттерне MVVM выводить сообщения о работе программы,
 00:00:00 Выполнена функция 1
 00:00:00 Выполнена функция 2
и тд.
Я понимаю, что  это логгирование и смотрю в строну nlog, все его хвалят, но он там пишет в файл, конечно можно потом все считать из файла и вывести на форму, но это как то не правильно, или мне проще написать свой класс в котором есть метод, который пишет разные сообщения в разных методах, эти сообщения добавляются например в массив и потом через свойства дублировать в текстбокс, но хочется делать это в реальном времени.  Сделать можно. но вопрос в том, как правильно сделать. Спасибо за ответы.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю лучше сделать свой велосипед. Для практики будет очень полезно.

Не совсем готовая реализация, скорее пища для размышлений

```
class MyLogger 
{
    private TextBox _textbox;

    public MyLogger(ref TextBox textbox) => _textbox = textbox;

    public void WriteLog(string message) 
    {
        _textBox.AppendText(String.Format("{0} {1}", 
            DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), message));
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я видел подобный пример, но вопрос в том, если  функции, которые я хочу выводить будут лежать в разных классах\методах, и как мне все это агрегирвоать в одном месте, и затем выводить все.

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch самое простое, сделать у класса статическое свойство Instance, в котором будет ссылка на экземпляр логгера. Так называемый синглтон.

Comment: Да с Синглтоном  думаю хорошо, ибо экземпляр логера нужен в единственном экземпляре.